# how to reset Xamarin license

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I am using Xamarin with Visual Studio 2015.

A few days ago I upgraded my Xamarin-account from the standard/free license to a trial-business license, however since then I decided that I don't need the business license. So now I want to return my account to the normal/free version/license (because the apps built with the trial-business-license only work for 24 hours).

However it is not clear to me at all how to reset the license of my Xamarin-account.

I guess a solution would be to make a new Xamarin-account, however this seems a unsatisfactory solution to me.

Comment: Since spring 2016, Xamarin is included in Visual Studio for free. There is no more business licence. Just update your Visual Studio to the newest update and you can use Xamarin without Xamarin account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just log out of your Xamarin Account and you should automatically be using the community edition.

If you need your Xamarin account to get components from the component store and this trial stuff is giving you problems. I advise you to contact Xamarin and have them help you clear out your issues.

Make sure that your Visual Studio is up to date.

Comment: I am too facing similar issue .I have purchased license for Visual Studio Enterprise. But as my Xamarin account is still tagged to other team, I cannot use Xamarin. I dropped a mail to "hello@xamarin.com" but did not receive any response from them. I even called the toll free number and dropped message but did not get any response yet.
Can you please let me know what is the contact email Id for xamarin apart from hello@xamarin.com?

Comment: hello@xamarin.com should give you a response. I am not a Xamarin employee, so I cant help you further.